# Remove lines from list

Tags: shell, ksh

Need your help with script that removes lines with "for" command .

```
file1  - contains list of servers
dog
cat
eel
ape
```

And then do some things (ping for example) with every single row 
but every time it removes the first line from list …

this is what I did, but it dosnt work well

```
#!/bin/ksh -x
for server in `cat file1`
do
ping $server 
sed '1d' file1
done
```

in the end of the script, file1 is supposed to be empty.
Thanks

Asaf

Comment: 1.  Kill the `cat`, use `read` instead.  2. `sed` does not alter the input file, it writes to stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also delete one line from it everytime it's read. With this if the script is interrupted what remains in "$FILE" are the only ones that weren't processed yet.

```
FILE=<filename>
while read SERVER < "$FILE"; do
    sed -i 1d "$FILE"
    ping "$SERVER"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` does not alter the input file, it only alters its pattern buffer, which is written to stdout (by default).  You cannot edit a file in place with `sed`.  I would prefer this:

```
while read server
do
    ping "$server" 
done < file1

# empty the file
> file1
```

But if you really must keep the file in step, then:

```
while read server < file1
do
    ping "$server"
    tail -n +2 file1 > file1.new
    mv file1.new file1
done
```

This is horrible!

Comment: Actually you can edit a file in place with `sed` , see the `-i` option

Comment: @CCH: the `-i` option is a GNU extension, it is not in POSIX/SUS.

Answer (score 0):

If it is supposed to be empty at the end, empty it after the loop :

```
for server in `cat file1`
do
ping $server 
done
echo '' > file
```

Otherwise, add -i to sed to edit the source file :

```
for server in `cat file1`
do
ping $server 
sed -i '1d' file1
done
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for that fast reply.
do you have an exple how to do it with read?
it suppose to be with loop.